# Wishlist toggle icon button not working in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

[Image for refrence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QLRF.jpg)

I am building a react js app where i have multiple rooms in my home screen i m fetching their data from firestore. on each room items i have a icon button for add that room to user's "wishlist" which is initially a outline_heart icon when user click that it add that particular room to the wishlist page in the app and also save the data to firebase.  after room add to the wishlist it changes itself from outline_heart icon to heart_fill_dark icon. (please check the image) this all is working now problem is that as soon i refresh the page the icons which were heart_fill_dark(when user add the data to wishlist) changes itself to outline_heart while its data is still in the wishlist. i have no idea why this is happening.

my icon code in the component is

```
<i className='text-4xl hrt' onClick={(e)=> AddWishlist(curElm, i ,e)}>              
              {wishlist[i] && currentUser ? <AiFillHeart /> : <AiOutlineHeart /> } 
</i>
```

data adding on the icon button click

```
// Adding Data to Wishlist
   const AddWishlist = (curUserData, i, e) =>{
        
// this code to make button toggle
    const newWishlist = [...wishlist]
    newWishlist[i] = !newWishlist[i]
    setWishlist(newWishlist)

    if(newWishlist[i] === true){
    dataref.collection("WishlistWeb").doc(currentUser).collection("wishlistDetails").doc(curUserData.id).set(curUserData).then(()=>{
     toast.success("Added to Wishlist")
    })
   }else{

    const docRef = dataref.collection("WishlistWeb").doc(currentUser);
    docRef.collection("wishlistDetails").doc(curUserData.id).delete()
    .then(() => {
       toast.success("Item Deleted From Wishlist")
    }).catch((error) => {

       console.error('Error Deleting Document',  error)
    })
   }}
```

I am new to react please guide me how can i solve this that if the data is in the wishlist and user has not removed it by clicking again button icon should not changes by itself.

Comment: how do you get `wishlist` initially ?

Comment: hey i am getting wishlist data from the firestore in the wishlist component. and because i have a hear button on home page so when user click that button the data added to the firestore wishlist section and the hear icon changes to dark.

Comment: what does `setWishlist(newWishlist)` do? `wishlist` will be update when firestore update. so every time when execute ` if(newWishlist[i] === true)`  `newWishlist[i] ` will be always the same. so try change it to `if(wishlist[i] === true)` and remove ` const newWishlist = [...wishlist]
    newWishlist[i] = !newWishlist[i]`

Comment: in the  setWishlist(newWishlist) i am setting the value of of true or false so i can toggle the button wishlist

Comment: did you try  what I said in last comment? if `wishlist` is connected with your firestore correctly you do not need ` newWishlist` in your `AddWishlist ` function. cause `wishlist` will update when the data in  firestore been updated. thats how firestore works!